# dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdCSs18_HeapBufferStorage using Accept Mobile SDK for iOS in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using Authorize.Net Accept Mobile SDK for iOS for mobile payment in ObjectiveC. The sample app is in swift and I want to use this sdk in my ObjectiveC code but I am getting this error while running the app:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdCSs18_HeapBufferStorage
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DB54650F-D40C-40C7-891F-6522E0B461AB/AccepectSdkDemo.app/Frameworks/AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK
Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DB54650F-D40C-40C7-891F-6522E0B461AB/AccepectSdkDemo.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DB54650F-D40C-40C7-891F-6522E0B461AB/AccepectSdkDemo.app/Frameworks/AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK
```

I have install the sdk using manual installation of the sdk. Here is the link [to implement the SDK](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-ios). 
This library is in swift so I have performed the steps to use Swift code into ObjectiveC already.

Any help is greatly appreciated.